# Most efficient way to distribute non unique elements across multiple lists

Tags: c#, optimization

Suppose that I have a list of integer or whatever

```
List<int> motherlist = { 1, 1, 2, 5, 7, 2, 2, 2, 6, 1 }

Console.WriteLine(children.Count); // 10
```

I would like to find all duplicates and not remove them from the list but to distribute them across other lists so the final count of all childrens should be the same as motherlist:

```
List<List<int>> children = { { 1, 2, 5, 7, 6 }, { 1, 2 }, { 1, 2 }, { 2 }}

Console.WriteLine(children.Sum(l => l.Count())); // 10 same as mother
```

I tried so far a brute force approach by looping through all elements of mother, comparing the elements with all other elements and to check for duplicates, If duplicate found I add it to a list of buckets (List of Lists) and so forth until the last elements.
But the brute force approach takes 7 CPU seconds for only a mother list of 300 items.
I imagine that if I had 1000 items this would take forever.

Is there a faster way to do this in C# .NET ?

Comment: Should the order of the elements in the mother list be kept?

Comment: Motherlist is not my concern. I need as a result many children whose particular values i can reorder if needed later.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest *grouping* duplicates and then *loop* taking into account size of the groups:

```
public static IEnumerable<List<T>> MyDo<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, 
                                           IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = null) {
  if (null == source)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));

  var groups = new Dictionary<T, List<T>>(comparer ?? EqualityComparer<T>.Default);

  int maxLength = 0;

  foreach (T item in source) {
    if (!groups.TryGetValue(item, out var list)) 
      groups.Add(item, list = new List<T>());
    
    list.Add(item);
    maxLength = Math.Max(maxLength, list.Count);
  }
  
  for (int i = 0; i < maxLength; ++i) {
    List<T> result = new List<T>();

    foreach (var value in groups.Values)
      if (i < value.Count)
        result.Add(value[i]);

    yield return result;
  }
}
```

**Demo:**

```
  int[] source = new int[] { 1, 1, 2, 5, 7, 2, 2, 2, 6, 1 };

  var result = MyDo(source).ToList();

  string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result
    .Select(line => $"[{string.Join(", ", line)}]"));

  Console.Write(report);
```

**Outcome:**

```
[1, 2, 5, 7, 6]
[1, 2]
[1, 2]
[2]
```

**Stress Demo:**

```
  Random random = new Random(1234); // seed, the results to be reproducible

  // We don't want 1000 items be forever; let's try 1_000_000 items
  int[] source = Enumerable
    .Range(1, 1_000_000)
    .Select(x => random.Next(1, 1000))
    .ToArray();

  Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

  sw.Start();

  var result = MyDo(source).ToList();

  sw.Stop();

  Console.WriteLine($"Time: {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
```

**Outcome:** (may vary from workstation to workstation)

```
  Time: 50 ms
```

Comment: Your non-linq way to do it is probably way faster than mine, since there is no warmup

Comment: @Cid: True, but your solution still optimizes the critical part while keeping the non-critical part simple and readable. Thus, I'd prefer yours, if the extra micro-optimization is not required.

Comment: I just see that your approach is similar to [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67835519/284240). I'll delete mine then. You could rename the extension(who would use `MyDo`?) to `DistributeDuplicates`.

Answer (score 2):

I would `GroupBy` the elements of the list, and then use the count of elements to know the number of sublists an element has to be added in

```
List<int> motherlist = new List<int> { 1, 1, 2, 5, 7, 2, 2, 2, 6, 1 };
var childrens = motherlist.GroupBy(x => x).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count());
var result = new List<List<int>>();

foreach (var children in childrens)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < children.Count(); i++)
    {
        if (result.Count() <= i) result.Add(new List<int>());

        result[i].Add(children.Key);
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("{");
foreach (var res in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"\t{{ { string.Join(", ", res) } }}");
}
Console.WriteLine("}");
```

This outputs :

```
{
    { 2, 1, 5, 7, 6 }
    { 2, 1 }
    { 2, 1 }
    { 2 }
}
```

Comment: Use `List.Count` instead of `IEnumerable.Count()`

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick shot, but it seems to work quite well...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> motherlist = new List<int> { 1, 1, 2, 5, 7, 2, 2, 2, 6, 1 };

            var rnd = new Random(1);

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                motherlist.Add(rnd.Next(1, 200));
            }

            var resultLists = new List<IEnumerable<int>>();

            while (motherlist.Any())
            {
                var subList = motherlist.Distinct().OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
                subList.ForEach(x => motherlist.Remove(x));
                resultLists.Add(subList);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Dictionary<int, int>` to keep track of the number of occurrences of each element and build the child lists in a single iteration with *`O(n)`* time complexity(most of the time) and without any LINQ:

```
var motherlist = new List<int>() { 1, 1, 2, 5, 7, 2, 2, 2, 6, 1 };
var counts = new Dictionary<int, int>();
var children = new List<List<int>>();
foreach(var element in motherlist)
{
    counts.TryGetValue(element, out int count);
    counts[element] = ++count;
    if (children.Count < count)
    {
        children.Add(new List<int>() { element });
    }
    else
    {
        children[count - 1].Add(element);
    }
}
```

#### OUTPUT

```
{ 1, 2, 5, 7, 6 }
{ 1, 2 }
{ 2, 1 }
{ 2 }
```